# How to interpret double dots and lines with numbers above the staff

Tags: notation, sheet-music, terminology, repeats

I've been learning to play the piano by myself for a couple of months, and today I came across a song in my book that got me confused.

I know that double dots inside double bars means that you have to repeat that part, but what do you do when you also have lines and numbers above the staff?

I get that they are supposed to mark two different verses but I literally have no idea what bits I am supposed to glue together. Could you please explain to me how to "read" them properly (probably there are pieces/songs where there are more than two numbers)? Also, what are they called?

The song:
[image: Chiapanecas p. 1]

---

[image: Chiapanecas p.2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That indicates a "first ending" and "second ending".  You play from the beginning up until the repeat bar, including the part under the 1.  (That's the first ending).  Then you go back to the first repeat sign, and the second time through you skip the first ending and jump to the second ending (2.).

So for your first example, you'd play measures: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10

Comment: The two pictures are from the same song, first and second page. How should I combine the 1 from the 1st page with the 1 from the 2nd page? Sorry for asking again

Comment: You play the first page as I described, and then go on to the second page, also played as I described.  You don't jump from page 2 back to 1.  When you see the open repeat sign at the beginning of page 2 (bar 11), that means the next repeat goes back to bar 11.

Comment: That makes sense! I thought you have to jump between page 1 ad 2, but I guess that would be annoying. Thanks!